# String in Unique Key in Entity Framework

Tags: database, linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to put a string in Unique Key ?

```
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    public string TweetID { get; set; }
```

Because I need ID in primary key (it's ok) and TweetID in unique key (for no duplication in database)

**EDIT : I use Entity Framework 4 and MVC3**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define unique key on string column but you must do it in the database (as unique index) because none of current EF versions support unique keys.